# Color-coding for HTML stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 (Community edition) the HTML color-coding suddendly stopped working. The C# files looks fine but the `cshtml`-files look pretty white.

The only addon I'm running is Resharper 8, and I've tried suspending it which had no result.

[image]

Any clues on what's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried installing Visual Studio 2013 Color Theme Editor ? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe

Comment: Have you tried to reset your setting before installing any extensions?  in the import and export setting , choose reset all setting

Comment: You are welcome , I will post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Visual Studio 2013 Color Theme Editor , https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe :)